# Apple Match O-Linker Error when testing on iPad 4th gen

Tags: ios, ipad, build, ios6, ios-simulator

I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK the latest version, added `AdSupport`, `Accounts` and `Social` frameworks to my project along with the `FacebookSDK` framework. My project is targeted for iOS 5.1, works fine in the simulator, but when I try to test on my iPad 4th gen y get this:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/8vius/Projects/Work/Fonyk/Fonyk-iPhone/Fonyk/facebook-ios-sdk'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/8vius/Projects/Work/Fonyk/Fonyk-iPhone/../../Desktop/facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-6825350/build'


ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/8vius/Projects/Work/Fonyk/Fonyk-iPhone/Fonyk/libGoogleAnalytics.a for architecture armv7s
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is because the Facebook SDK isn't updated and doesn't match my current architecture for testing. To solve this issue go to Project -> Build Settings and change the valid architectures to armv7 for `Release`, `Ad-Hoc` and `Debug` (or just for the one you need right now). and set `Build Active Architecture Only` to No